# retrieve an image from a JSZip archive

Tags: javascript, image, jszip

I stored an image in a JSZip archive and need to retrieve it and display it.

The zip object has a data field which holds the binary data.

I got the data now, but I cannot use it to create an image like this:

```
var img = new Image();
image.src = dataUrlFromJZip;
```

I'm relatively lost as to what I need to do. I know that the data cannot be used in it's current form, but I'm not sure what the solution is.

Any help is appreaciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried

```
var img = new Image();
image.src = "data:image/png;base64," + dataUrlFromJZip;
```

(replace png if necessary)